# VSCode error at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16) at bootstrap_node.js:618:3

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I run the NodeJs with this command in VS code:

At prompt> node index.js

in index.js , I have below:
app.listen(5000,() => console.log('Server started'))

Below is the error msg

**at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16) at bootstrap_node.js:618:3**

What this error mean? how to solve?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This isn't the error. This is a small section of the Backtrace to the error. The first line usually looks like `[Something]Error: this is some error` (e.g. `TypeError: cannot read property 'foo' of null`)

Comment: Thanks. How to know which line caused the error in which file? BTW I m newbie in VSC